# PHP loop place every 3rd loop in row

Tags: php

I want to add 3 divs in a row through a loop in PHP. 
For example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> Item 1 </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> Item 2 </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> Item 3 </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> Item 4 </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> Item 5 </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> Item 6 </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I did a few searches on Stackoverflow but I didn't find a good solution. Who can help me? This is my PHP code so far, but as you see, it place only 1 item in a row

```
for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
   if ($i % 3 == 0) {
      $content .= "<div class='row'>";
   }

   $content.= "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item ". $i ."</div></div>";

   if ($i % 3 == 0) {
     $content .= "</div>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Why one extra closing div in `$content.= "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item ". $i ."</div></div>";` ??

Comment: I suggest, your code wrap every third row, instead of block of three rows )

Comment: because I copied to much code ;) Originally I have other content in the div ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it and cope with odd numbers in `$limit`

```
$limit = 9;
$content = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $content .= "\n<div class='row'>";
    }
    // remove the extra `</div>` from this line
    //$content.= "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item ". $i ."</div></div>";

    $content.= "\n\t<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item$i</div>";

    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
        $content .= "\n</div>";
    }
}
//cope with odd numbers in $limit
if ( $i%3 != 0) {
    $content .= "\n</div>";
}
echo $content;
```

Result:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item0</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item1</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item2</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item3</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item4</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item5</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item6</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item7</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item8</div>
</div>
```

Or with $limit set to an odd number like 5

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item 1</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item 2</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item 3</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item 4</div>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested `foreach` loops instead if you put your numbers into a multidimensional array.

```
foreach (array_chunk(range(1, $limit), 3) as $row) {
    $content .= "<div class='row'>";
    foreach ($row as $i) {
        $content .= "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>Item ". $i ."</div>";
    }
    $content .= "</div>";
}
```

`array_chunk(range(1, $limit), 3)` will produce an array like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. This will use slightly more memory, but I prefer the simpler code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was referring to the additional dimension created by `array_chunk`

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt get that :)